# Как сверстать блоки табами по 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

В десктопной версии это выглядит вот так http://prntscr.com/om0l1m
А для мобильной версии нужно вот так http://prntscr.com/om0maz
Как реализовать в мобильной версии такие табы (табы слайдер) ?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Comment: По поводу если нужен слайдер, то я бы смотрел в сторону готовых решений, которые уже адаптированы ко многим девайсам

Comment: а какие есть готовые решения. Я гуглил часа 2 наверно не нашел.

Comment: Готовых решений именно по данному вопросу не скажу. Могу сказать, что иногда нормальное решение приходилось искать по нескольку дней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не идеально работает, но суть, думаю, должна быть понятна

```
https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/LwyZZZ
```

```js
function showSchedule(id) {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('schedules__list');
  var el = document.getElementById('schedule' + id);

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.display = "none";
    els[i].removeAttribute('style');
  }
  els[0].style.display = "none";
  el.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* ..names */

.names {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  padding: 15px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.names__item {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 7 - 10px);
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ..schedules */

.schedules {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

.schedules__list {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 7 - 10px);
  list-style: none;
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .names {
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
  .schedules__list {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .schedules__list:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .schedules__list {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* ..training */

.training {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #E30613;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <ul class="names">
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(1)">Понедельник</li>
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(2)">Вторник</li>
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(3)">Среда</li>
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(4)">Четверг</li>
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(5)">Пятница</li>
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(6)">Суббота</li>
    <li class="names__item" onclick="showSchedule(7)">Воскресенье</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="schedules" id="schedules">
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule1">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Понедельник</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Понедельник</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule2">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Вторник</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Вторник</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule3">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Среда</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Среда</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule4">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Четверг</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Четверг</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule5">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Пятница</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Пятница</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule6">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Суббота</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Суббота</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="schedules__list" id="schedule7">
      <li class="training schedule__training">
        <p class="training__place">Воскресенье</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Воскресенье</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
      <li class="training">
        <p class="training__place">Уличная площадка</p>
        <h3 class="training__name">Функциональная тренировка</h3>
        <p class="training__gender">женская</p>
        <p class="training__coach">Анна Мацкевич</p>
        <p class="training__time">19.00 - 20.00</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Но вопрос немного не тот.  Как сделать чтоб сами табы прокручивались без полосы прокрутки.  http://prntscr.com/omcdt1

Comment: @Дмитрий, так при просмотре с мобильного полоса прокрутки скрывается. Даже в браузере при эмуляции мобильного это видно

Comment: к примеру навигацию табов  в слайдер засунуть и показывать по 3 . Как в макете http://prntscr.com/omck17